# how to echo session data to view profile

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

how to echo session data to view profile using codeigniter or help me to pass id with session to get user profile

controller

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller 
{    
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('User_Model');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->library('parser');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    public function register()
    {
        $this->load->view('Register');
    }
    public function Save()
    {           
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
        {
            echo 'Please enter correct email.';
            exit;
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
        {               
            echo 'Please enter password.';
            exit;
        }

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {               
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = md5(trim($this->input->post('password')));
            $res = $this->User_Model->Save($email,$password);
            exit;
        }
    }
    public function Login()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'email', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
        {
            echo 'Please enter correct email.';
            exit;
        }

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
        {               
            echo 'Please enter password.';
            exit;
        }

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true)
        {               
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $password = md5(trim($this->input->post('password')));
            $res = $this->User_Model->login($email,$password);
            echo $res; 
            exit;
        }
    }
    public function dashboard()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome');
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect(base_url().'index.php/User/'); 
    }
}   
?>
```

Comment: only add relevant controller, model, view

Answer (score 0):

1. Using raw php, you check session data using `$_SESSION`
2. Inside codeigniter, you can check session data using `print_r($this->session->all_userdata());`

Comment: CI offers `$this->session->has_userdata('some_key')` method that returns `true || false` and can be used for check.

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter follows the MVC design model this means that data is first generated by a module is passed then to a controller and finally the controller inflates data into a certain view.

### Load a view from Controller

```
$this->load->view('view_name', $data, true/false);
```

in this example you see how to load a view passing to it some data.

So assuming you have a view in your view folder called `show_session.php`
we can create the following method in the controller to show the session data you want the user to be able to see.

```
public function index()
{
    $data['info'] = $this->session->all_userdata(); 
    $this->load->view('show_session',$data);
}
```

### Create the view

In case you don't have that view you create it with the following contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple data</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
foreach ($info as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." => ".$value."<br>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

finally save it into `/application/views` folder.

Credit and more info: [here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-views-templating-in-codeigniter--net-25648)